# Populating a QComboBox and a QTable[View|Widget] from javascript

Tags: qt, qcombobox

I'm trying to write a script for an application developed with Qt, using javascript for the business logic and a .ui file for the GUI, but I'm facing two problems.

1. In the ui I declared a `QComboBox`, to which I successfully connect javascript functions to handle
   signals such as `editTextChanged`, etc. I was wondering I cannot populate the combobox from within
   javascript code, because the `addItem` function is not exposed to script-side code.

   ```
   combobox.editTextChanged[action](ComboBoxChanged);  // OK (action is "connect" or "disconnect")
   combobox.addItem("element 1");   // Error!
   ```

   Is there any (other) way to do this?
2. I need to show a set of items (strings) in a table-like component. I tried using a `QTableView` and
   `QTableWidget` but I cannot insert or get items. For example, from javascript I cannot access the
   `setModel` function of a `QTableView` (if at least I could create a `QAbstractItemModel` from
   script...), neither I can access the `item(row,col)` function of a `QTableWidget` class, to set an
   item's text. Is there any way to show a table of strings to the user, let edit them and retrieve
   the modified contents?

Thanks in advance.

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

Because the addItem() function isn't a slot, you'll need an intermediate public slot to handle the transaction. It'll be the same with the other functions you are trying to get at as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The problem is that I cannot use C++ because I'm writing just a script for an application. I can make use of javascript only (and of XML for the .ui file).

So there isn't any way to do that from script?